# Change rotate direction of div after every 5 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two div(i.e div1 and div2), div1 rotate anticlockwise direction and other div2 rotate in clockwise direction. Now i want both div change their rotation direction after each 5 second continuously, like if div1 rotate clockwise after 5 second it rotate anticlockwise then after 5 second clockwise direction and so on continuously. same process applied in another div..

```
<div id="div1" style="height:100px; width:100px; border:2px solid gray">div1 </div>
<div id="div2" style="margin-top:100px; height:100px; width:100px; border:2px solid Red">div2</div>

<script>
     rotate(0,0);
     function rotate(degree1, degree2) {
            $("#div1").css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree1 + 'deg)' });
            $("#div2").css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree2 + 'deg)' });
            $("#div1").css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree1 + 'deg)'}); 
            $("#div2").css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree2 + 'deg)'}); 
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                rotate(++degree1, --degree2);
                }, 5);
            } 
</script>
```

Comment: `$ $("#div2").css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree2 + 'deg)'});` there is a `$` which shouldn't be there. Anyway I haven't really understood, you want your divs to change their rotation direction every 5 seconds?

Comment: It was a typo @LightStyle

Comment: setTimeout has as 2nd parameter miliseconds, not seconds, so shoud be `5000`

Comment: you can combine your `.css()` calls and also store your #div1 and #div2 jQuery objects outside of the function, so you won't have to search the entire document for them each iteration. (Or at least specify a better context than the whole Document)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood your problem correctly, this is the code you need(and here is a [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sdzn9/)):

```
var invert = false;
startRotating();
function startRotating() {
    rotate(0, 0);
    setTimeout(invertRotate, 5000);
}
function invertRotate() {
    invert = !invert;
    setTimeout(invertRotate, 5000);
}
function rotate(degree1, degree2) {
    $("#div1").css({
        WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree1 + 'deg)'
    });
    $("#div2").css({
        WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree2 + 'deg)'
    });
    $("#div1").css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree1 + 'deg)'
    });
    $("#div2").css({
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree2 + 'deg)'
    });
    setTimeout(function () {
        invert ? rotate(++degree1, --degree2) : rotate(--degree1, ++degree2);
    }, 5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="div1" style="height:100px; width:100px; border:2px solid gray">div1 </div>
<div id="div2" style="margin-top:100px; height:100px; width:100px; border:2px solid Red">div2</div>

<script>
     rotate(0,0,0);
     function rotate(degree1, degree2, timepassed) {
            $("#div1").css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree1 + 'deg)' });
            $("#div2").css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree2 + 'deg)' });
            $("#div1").css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree1 + 'deg)'}); 
            $("#div2").css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree2 + 'deg)'}); 
            var orientation = 1 - (Math.round(timepassed/5000)%2)*2;
            setTimeout(function () {
                rotate(degree1 + orientation, degree2 - orientation, timepassed+5);
                }, 5);
            } 
</script>
```

You have to pass the time passed. Another way would be to calculate it from an startpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
 var counter = 0; var reverse = false;
    rotate(0,0);
    function rotate(degree1, degree2) {
        $("#div1").css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree1 + 'deg)' });
        $("#div2").css({ WebkitTransform: 'rotate(' + degree2 + 'deg)' });
        $("#div1").css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree1 + 'deg)'}); 
        $("#div2").css({ '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree2 + 'deg)'}); 
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            counter += 5;
            if (counter == 5000) { counter = 0; reverse = reverse ? false : true;}
            if (reverse) rotate(--degree1, ++degree2);
            else rotate(++degree1, --degree2);
        }, 5);
    }
```

Use a global counter and bool. When the counter hits the time target, toggle the bool. Call your rotate function based on bool value.